# Upload txt file from c++ console application

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, file, file-upload, console-application

I crated a console application that stores all user inputs into a .txt file.
Now I want to upload this txt file to somethig like Dropbox or it could be something else.
Would you give me some tipps how to do this? What should I look for in order to do this?

I found this link to MS page that could be the solution for my problem: [MS-LINK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36s52zhs.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-3)

In this case I need an ASP.NET Webseite where I have to upload the file to.

Is there another possibility? Like uploading this directly to Dropbox for example?

Comment: You can't do this with plain C++ so you need a library for that, or you have to use the windows-API

Comment: @TNA hi, what library should I use?

Comment: Probably Curl http://curl.haxx.se/ will do but it's a C API and there may be better solutions. Maybe Boost.asio is ok.

Comment: @TNA thanks I will look for this librarys

Answer (score 2):

This should be a comment, but my rep seems to be too low. Why dont you just save the file to the folder, which dropbox/Google drive checks for files to sync with the cloud?

Comment: you are right this could be very usefull. I said dropbox because I wanted to give an example of what I want to do. I would appreciate if someone could give me a hint in how to upload text files to a page like that [link](http://www.filesnack.com/)